# Remapping Caps Lock to left control, and left control to Super key using xmodmap

Tags: keyboard, xmodmap

I've been checking out other questions regarding xmodmap, but couldn't find a solution to my situation. I got an old IBM keyboard that doesn't have a Windows/super key, and would like to remap the Caps Lock to left control, and left control to Super key. I was using gnome-tweak-tool but it stopped working yesterday.

I've got a partial solution using xmodmap in my ~/.xmodmap-ibmkb:

```
remove Lock = Caps_Lock
keysym Caps_Lock = Control_L
add Control = Control_L
add mod4 = Super_L Hyper_L
keysym Control_L = Super_L Hyper_L
```

This works fine in making the Caps Lock a Control_L, and Control_L as a Windows/Super key, but my shortcuts involving the super key are not working. For example, using Super+E to launch the home folder. And I'm using Solus Budgie as my OS.

Your answers and suggestions will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!